# Define a String constant in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, constants

Is it possible in SQL Server to define a String constant? I am rewriting some queries to use stored procedures and each has the same long string as part of an IN statement [a], [b], [c] etc.

It isn't expected to change, but could at some point in future. It is also a very long string (a few hundred characters) so if there is a way to define a global constant for this that would be much easier to work with.

If this is possible I would also be interested to know if it works in this scenario. I had tried to pass this String as a parameter, so I could control it from a single point within my application but the Stored Procedure didn't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a table with a single column and row and disallow writes on it.

Use that as you global string constant (or additional constants, if you wish).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for one thing (a string constant in MS SQL), but appear to maybe need something else. The reason I say this is because you have given a few hints at your ultimate objective, which appears to be using the same IN clause in multiple stored procedures.

The biggest clue is in the last sentence:

> I had tried to pass this String as a
>   parameter, so I could control it from
>   a single point within my application
>   but the Stored Procedure didn't like
>   it.

Without details of your SQL scripts, I am going to attempt to use some [psychic debugging](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=psychic%20debugging#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=psychic%20debugging&aq=f&aqi=p-p1g-v1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a316b5cdb3fe9040) techniques to see if I can get you to what I believe is your actual goal, and not necessarily your stated goal.

Given your Stored Procedure "didn't like that" when you tried to pass in a string as a parameter, I am guessing the composition of the string was simply a delimited list of values, something like "10293, 105968, 501940" or "Juice, Milk, Donuts" (pay no attention to the actual list values - the important part is the delimited list itself). And your SQL may have looked something like this (again, ignore the specific names and focus on the general concept):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM UnknownTable
WHERE Column1 IN (@parameterString);
```

If this approximately describes the path you tried to take, then you will need to reconsider your approach. Using a regular T-SQL statement, you will not be able to pass a string of parameter values to an IN clause - it just doesn't know what to do with them.

There are alternatives, however:

1. [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) - you can build up the
   whole SQL statement, parameters and
   all, then execute that in the SQL
   database. This probably is not what
   you are trying to achieve, since you
   are moving script to stored
   procedures. But it is listed here
   for completeness.
2. Table of values -
   you can create a single-column table
   that holds the specific values you
   are interested in. Then your Stored
   Procedure can simply use the column
   from this table for the IN clause).
   This way, there is no Dynamic SQL
   required. Since you indicate that
   the values are not likely to change,
   you may just need to populate the
   table once, and use it wherever
   appropriate.
3. [String Parsing](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV) to
   derive the list of values - You can
   pass the list of values as a string,
   then implement code to parse the
   list into a table structure on the
   fly. An alternative form of this
   technique is to pass an XML
   structure containing the values, and
   use MS SQL Server's XML
   functionality to derive the table.
4. Define a table-value function that
   returns the values to use - I have
   not tried this one, so I may be
   missing something, but you should be
   able to define the values in a
   table-value function (possibly using
   a bunch of UNION statements or
   something), and call that function
   in the IN clause. Again - this is an
   untested suggestion and would need
   to be worked through to determine
   it's feasibility.

I hope that helps (assuming I have guessed your underlying quandary).

For future reference, it would be extremely helpful if you could include SQL script showing 
your table structure and stored procedure logic so we can see what you have *actually* attempted. This will considerably improve the effectiveness of the answers you receive. Thanks.

P.S. The link for String Parsing actually includes a large variety of techniques for passing arrays (i.e. lists) of information to Stored Procedures - it is a very good resource for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to string-constants tables as Oded suggests, I have used scalar functions to encapsulate some constants. That would be better for fewer constants, of course, but their use is simple.

Perhaps a combination - string constants table with a function that takes a key and returns the string. You could even use that for localization by having the function take a 'region' and combine that with a key to return a different string!